# null session on page method

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm using InProc session state and for some odd reason, the session variables are always **null when I'm using a page method**.

If I do this:

```
var test = HttpContext.Current.Session["test"];
```

it's showing nothing when I'm running on a page method but if I continue debugging and open another page, it's showing its expected result. I can't post all the code of the app so where should I start looking?

web.config file looks like this:

```
  <sessionState mode="InProc"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: well start by explaining in what context you use the code above. Is this in the code-behinde of some page (I guess yes) - did you set some value to "test" before this?

Comment: Are you setting that variable before using it? Are you running that web application on a farm? InProc session state doesn't meant to be used on this scenario.

Comment: The above code sits both in a page method and in 2 different aspx pages code behind. The variable is set to value "testworks?" in the master page. When I debug the aspx pages test holds the variable but when I debug the page method, the variable is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are setting "test " in a `masterpage` it will be null in the `webmethod`.  A `webmethod` doesn't know anything about `masterpages`.

```
 [System.Web.Services.WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
 public static string Bla(double bla)
 {
     //code here
     var test = HttpContext.Current.Session["test"];

 }
```

Comment: I added the enablesession parameter but it's still not working. I'm baffled; it used to work. On a side note, the page method is declared static.

Comment: I set the session in the master page, and then it should be retrievable when I use a page method; that's the problem. The session works in aspx pages but not in page methods